# How can I scope a resource so that the path helpers are scoped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Super simple goal that doesn't seem to be well documented, I'd like to scope a resource & have the path (& url) helpers generate the scoped paths.

ie:

```
scope :info do
  resources :publications
end

publications_path => '/info/publications'
publication_path => '/info/publications/:id'
edit_publication_path => '/info/publications/:id/edit'
```

I'd even be fine with 'info_' prefixed path helpers, but as is they aren't being generated. So what's the magic to make this work?

rake routes gives:

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
    publications GET    /publications(.:format)                 publications#index
                 POST   /publications(.:format)                 publications#create
 new_publication GET    /publications/new(.:format)             publications#new
edit_publication GET    /publications/:id/edit(.:format)        publications#edit
     publication GET    /publications/:id(.:format)             publications#show
                 PATCH  /publications/:id(.:format)             publications#update
                 PUT    /publications/:id(.:format)             publications#update
                 DELETE /publications/:id(.:format)             publications#destroy
                 GET    /info/publications(.:format)            publications#index
                 POST   /info/publications(.:format)            publications#create
                 GET    /info/publications/new(.:format)        publications#new
                 GET    /info/publications/:id/edit(.:format)   publications#edit
                 GET    /info/publications/:id(.:format)        publications#show
                 PATCH  /info/publications/:id(.:format)        publications#update
                 PUT    /info/publications/:id(.:format)        publications#update
                 DELETE /info/publications/:id(.:format)        publications#destroy
```

Comment: What you get when you run `rake routes`

Comment: added rake routes output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I watch your `rake routes` output I can only guess, but I am sure that you have duplicate `resources :publications`.

I think you have

```
resources :publications
....
scope :info do
  resources :publications
end
```

The first line generates resources for publications and you get

```
publications_path => 'publications'
```

then

`publications_path` is taken and your
`/info/publications` has no method name

Comment: doh, forgot about the generator adding that to routes.rb, thanks.